# Why i get this error in radio group style

Tags: android, xml, radio-group

What i have is an android activity with xml style .. i have two radio box and two text view with auto complete text view , the thing is i made a style with table layout to order my layout and here is my xml :

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                    android:paddingRight="7dp"
                    android:text="الرجاء اختيار اسم العميل "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="الصيدليات"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiolang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       >
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<!-- // here is error it says :The element type "RadioGroup" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</RadioGroup>".             -->
 </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:text="العملاء"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                  </RadioGroup>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtsearch2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
                    android:background="#ff9900"
                    android:text="متابعة"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

And the thing is a have a table row before the other radio box , how can i fix it so my radio group control the two radio boxes?? without destroying my style?

Comment: @screen First of all improve your xml code check it properly. First RadioButton must be enclosed in RadioGroup. You have enclosed that with TableGroup. What the heck???

Comment: this is by mistake .. i will update my question .. but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Update your xml file with this code

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                android:text="الرجاء اختيار اسم العميل "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiolang"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="الصيدليات"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="العملاء"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsearch2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        </RadioGroup>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
                android:background="#ff9900"
                android:text="متابعة"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: can u please post your full xml file? @sereen

Comment: first `</RadioGroup>` and then `</TableRow>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                android:paddingRight="7dp"
                android:text="الرجاء اختيار اسم العميل "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="الصيدليات"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radiolang"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="العملاء"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioGroup>
            </RadioGroup>

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtsearch2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
                    android:background="#ff9900"
                    android:text="متابعة"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />
            </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```